# Disable Orientation in iphone app. iOS 7 - Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation, landscape

I created iphone and ipad app using Xcode 5, iOS 7.

My app contains `UIViewControllers` and `UITableViewControllers`. I want to stop landscape orientation in the whole app.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this image, it shows in the bottom where you can specify which interface orientation your target app will have. You just have to select Portrait and upside down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on your projects name, under the "General" tab in the "Deployment Info" section, there's an option called "Device Orientation".  Simply check portrait, and uncheck everything else.